# Resample a value into smaller values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

```
2020-04-02 00:00:00+03:00    32.7171
2020-04-02 00:15:00+03:00        NaN
2020-04-02 00:30:00+03:00        NaN
2020-04-02 00:45:00+03:00        NaN
2020-04-02 01:00:00+03:00    70.2465
2020-04-02 01:15:00+03:00        NaN
2020-04-02 01:30:00+03:00        NaN
2020-04-02 01:45:00+03:00        NaN
```

I have this type of dataframe, this is showing solar energy production between 00:00:00 -> 01:00:00 and 01:00:00 -> 02:00:00 hours

I need to distribute the values 32.7171 and 70.2465 in their respective hours, It means that the SUM of values between 00:00:00 -> 01:00:00 should not be greater than 32.7171 because this is the total energy that will be produced in that complete hour, same goes to the interval between 01:00:00 -> 02:00:00

The simplest case is that I divide 32.7171 and 70.2465 equally to 4 parts and assign the value to respective rows (4 rows in 1 hour each 15 minutes)

The interpolation is simply filling NaNs and the sum of values between 1 hour intervals is incorrect. The same goes with scipy resampling.

Is there a better solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would groupby the hour and transform mean:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df['value'] = (df['value'].fillna(0)
                   .groupby(df['time'].dt.floor('H'))
                   .transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
                       time      value
0 2020-04-02 00:00:00+03:00   8.179275
1 2020-04-02 00:15:00+03:00   8.179275
2 2020-04-02 00:30:00+03:00   8.179275
3 2020-04-02 00:45:00+03:00   8.179275
4 2020-04-02 01:00:00+03:00  17.561625
5 2020-04-02 01:15:00+03:00  17.561625
6 2020-04-02 01:30:00+03:00  17.561625
7 2020-04-02 01:45:00+03:00  17.561625
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already have this type of solution, I actually don't want to distribute values uniformly or equally, is there a way to achieve that?